# escape wildcard in between and operator

Tags: oracle, wildcard, between

For example, I have a table name test_table and has a column named column_A which has values:

```
A_1
A_2
A_3
A1
A2
A3
B_1
B_2
B_3
B1
B2
B3
```

If i want to select all the data has `A_` as the beginning, i can use escape `\` like:

```
select * from test_table where column_A like 'A\_*' escape '\';
```

so that `_` not treated as a single character wildcard. i can get A_1, A_2 and A_3.

How should i do when i want use this in Between and operator? like

```
select * from test_table where column_A between 'A_\*' and 'B_\*'
```

i tried the above one, it didn't escape the `_`. if i add a escape right after condition like

```
select * from test_table 
 where column_A between 'A_\*' escape '\' and 'B_\*' escape '\'
```

or

```
select * from test_table 
 where column_A between 'A_\*' and 'B_\*' escape '\'
```

i got a syntax error.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to escape characters with the comparison operators because these operators don't treat ANY character as special. There are no wildcards characters with `BETWEEN`, therefore no need to escape them. What do you expect your query to return, it is really not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`BETWEEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions011.htm#sthref2010) doesn't <strike>seem to</strike> permit <strike>escaping of</strike> wildcards <strike>using that syntax</strike>; I assume you're getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended? (Always useful to actually state the error you're seeing). <strike>It does though allow the alternative syntax:</strike>

```
select * from test_table
where column_A between 'A[_]%' and 'B[_]%';
```

**Edit** Actually although the syntax is allowed, it isn't doing anything; `BETWEEN` isn't treating `_` as a wildcard anyway, though it does treat `%` as one.

**Edit 2** As @Allan pointed out, it really isn't treating `%` as a wildcard, that's just how the character ordering works.

I'm not sure that's what you actually want though, as it will give you `A_1, A_2, A_3, B1, B2, B3` (at least with my NLS parameters).

If what you actually want is `A_1, A_2, A_3, B_1, B_2, B_3` then you can use [`REGEXP_LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#sthref1983) instead, something like:

```
select * from test_table
where regexp_like(column_A, '^([AB])_';
```

(though I'll happily defer to others on the best way to construct that).

Comment: I don't think `between` is actually treating % as a wildcard. I believe it's returning those results because numeric values fall after the percent sign in the character table. That also explains why the "B_1", etc. values are not returned.

Comment: @Allan - yes, of course it is. D'oh. I was thinking it must be treating it as a wildcard because it still found records, but you're right, that's just because `%` has a lower ASCII (or unicode) value than alphanumerics. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You can't escape characters with the comparison operators because there are no wildcards with these operators. I don't think `BETWEEN` is the right operator for the task.

You seem to want all strings that start with a letter between A and B and are followed by a `_`. I would advise you to take a look at [`regexp_like`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#i1048942), which is more flexible than the `LIKE` operator. For example you could write:

```
SQL> WITH test_table AS (
  2     SELECT 'A_1' column_A FROM dual
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 'A_2' FROM dual
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 'A_3' FROM dual
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 'A1' FROM dual
  6     UNION ALL SELECT 'A2' FROM dual
  7     UNION ALL SELECT 'A3' FROM dual
  8     UNION ALL SELECT 'B_1' FROM dual
  9     UNION ALL SELECT 'B_2' FROM dual
 10     UNION ALL SELECT 'B_3' FROM dual
 11     UNION ALL SELECT 'B1' FROM dual
 12     UNION ALL SELECT 'B2' FROM dual
 13     UNION ALL SELECT 'B3' FROM dual
 14  )
 15  SELECT * FROM test_table
 16   WHERE regexp_like (column_A, '^[A-B]_.*');

COLUMN_A
--------
A_1
A_2
A_3
B_1
B_2
B_3
```